# Java: how to write regex for pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match every row in a CSV file that has the following structure (one row is shown):

```
9344949,HW488429,10/09/2013 05:00:00 AM,039XX W MONROE ST,0610,BURGLARY,FORCIBLE ENTRY,RESIDENCE,false,false,1122,011,28,26,05,1149955,1899326,2013,10/16/2013 12:39:00 AM,41.87966141386545,-87.72485045045373,"(41.87966141386545, -87.72485045045373)"
```

I have tried to write this pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("^([^,]+,){2}\\d{2}/\\d{2}/(\\d{4})([^,]+,){3}([^,]+)");
```

but it does not work, can anyone please help me with the correction? thanks!

Comment: *Don't* use a regular expression - I love regular expressions, but this is a questionable use-case. Use a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+csv) - or at least `String.split` (assuming that none of the data allows commas). *After* the data is extracted into tidy columns then each column can be dealt with individually (e.g. checking, converting, etc).

Comment: If you *do* wish to use a regular expression for the general extraction (uhg!), head over to any one of the online regular expression helpers/tester that have immediate-feedback matching and keep adding input and building the regular expression until "it works". YMMV.

Comment: That regex works for me; it matches everything up to and including the word `BURGLARY`.  Rounding up the usual suspects: Are you using the `matches()` method?  If so, use `find()` instead.  Are you reading the whole document into memory and working on it as one big string?  If you are, you should be setting the `MULTILINE` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I used the tool Expresso to construct some difficult regular expressions. Please have a try.

btw, Can you please give a few more sample rows so that the structure of the row will be better understood.?